# Invalid Controller Specified Error, even though the controller is present

Tags: zend-framework, deployment, zend-route, zend-controller

I have a camelcased controller name called MenuItem. And Also I have created a router for this particular controller as

```
    $routeMenuItem = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/menu-item/:action/:menu/:parent/:id/*', array(
        'controller'    => 'MenuItem',
        'action'        => 'index',
        'menu'          => 1,
        'parent'        => 0,
        'id'            => 0        
    ));
```

No, when I navigate to this route lets say `/menu-item/index/2` I get a error, `Invalid controller specified (MenuItem)` error.

However I am encountering this problem while **deploying under linux environment**. But, during development in Windows environment it **works fine**.

How to solve this?

### More Information

Controller:

```
File Name: MenuItemController.php
Class Name: MenuItemController
```

Stack Trace

```
#0 /../library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /../library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /../library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /../public/index.php(25): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}
```

Request Parameters

```
array (
  'action' => 'index',
  'menu' => '2',
  'controller' => 'MenuItem',
  'parent' => 0,
  'id' => 0,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Windows is not case sensitive and Linux based operating systems are.

From the ZendFramework manual:

> Zend_Controller’s dispatcher then takes the controller value and maps
>   it to a class. By default, it Title-cases the controller name and
>   appends the word Controller. Thus, in our example above, the
>   controller roadmap is mapped to the class RoadmapController.

This means that MenuItemController.php and MenuitemController.php are two different things, thus the autoloader is unable to find a match.

As a rule, when using multi word controllers just make sure that only the first letter of the class and the C in controller is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem in the past (I was also developing in Windows and deploying the application to a Linux server). My solution was to rename the classes and files, to remove the uppercases. In your case, it would be:

```
File Name: MenuitemController.php
Class Name: MenuitemController
```